# Upload failed via ftp.exe

Tags: php, windows, ftp, xampp

I am using xampp on Windows and want to upload an file via ftp.exe.
I created a .vbs script creating an ftp.dat file and run ftp.exe.

```
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FileIn = fs.OpenTextFile("C:\xampp\htdocs\ftp.dat", 2, true)
filein.WriteLine "open"
filein.WriteLine "IP"
filein.WriteLine "USER"
filein.WriteLine "PASSWORD"
filein.WriteLine "put C:\path\to\file\file.txt"
filein.WriteLine "quit"
filein.close

Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run "cmd /c ftp.exe -s:C:\xampp\htdocs\ftp.dat > log"
```

I printed the output to a log file giving me this error:

```
ftp> To Connected to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.
open
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
220 hostname FTP server ready.
User (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:(none)): 
331 Password required for USER.

230 User USER logged in.
ftp> put C:\path\to\file\file.txt
200 PORT command successful.
553 file.txt: Permission denied.

ftp> quit
221 Goodbye. You uploaded 0 bytes and downloaded 0 bytes.
```

When I run this .vbs file in the command line, everything works fine.
But if I run this using exec/system I get the error from above.

PHP File:

```
<? php
    exec('C:\\xampp\htdocs\\upload.vbs');
?>
```

Comment: you'd probably need `exec('cscript c:\......')` instead. exec() doesn't use a shell, and will try to execute the .vbs file as if was a .exe directly.

Comment: any reason you don't just do this from PHP? http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fput.php

Comment: A 553 error in FTP suggests that the FTP server is preventing you from creating a file. Check your FTP server permissions and try this from a different FTP client.

Comment: Show is output when *"running this .vbs file in the command line"* for comparison.